# Get data from database with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express

I start node.js with simple node example.

My simple project provide that to get data(select * from bla bla bla) from db but i have a problem is as follows:

> ```
> Error: No such database: hakan_billur
>     at Connection.parseE (C:\Users\hakan_billur\workspace\postgre-bilgi2\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:539:11)
>     at Connection.parseMessage (C:\Users\hakan_billur\workspace\postgre-bilgi2\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:366:17)
>     at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\hakan_billur\workspace\postgre-bilgi2\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:105:22)
>     at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17)
>     at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:163:16)
>     at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:126:10)
>     at TCP.onread (net.js:538:20)
> Program node ./bin/www exited with code 1
> ```

**database.js is as follows:**

```
var pg = require('pg');
var path = require('path');
var connectionString = require(path.join(__dirname, '../', '../', 'config'));
```

**config.js is as follows:**

```
var connectionString = process.env.DATABASE_URL || 'postgres://portal:por**tal@10.10.22.105:6432';

module.exports = connectionString;
```

**index.js is as follows:**

```
var express = require('express');

var router = express.Router();

var path = require('path');
var pg = require('pg');

var connectionString = require(path.join(__dirname, '../', '../', 'config'));

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
var results = [];

var client = new pg.Client(connectionString);
client.connect();

// Get a Postgres client from the connection pool
pg.connect(connectionString, function(err, client, done) {

// SQL Query > Insert Data
var query = client.query("SELECT * FROM poll where is_active=true");

query.on('row', function(row) {
    results.push(row);
});

console.log(results);

// After all data is returned, close connection and return results
query.on('end', function() {
    client.end();
    console.log(results);
    return res.json(results);
});

// Handle Errors
if(err) {
  console.log(err);
}
});

res.sendFile(res.render(path.join(__dirname, '../', '../', './client', 'views', 'index')));

});
```

and finally file hierarchy are as follows:

[image]

who can help me.Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What is the name of the database you are trying to connect to? You did not specify one in your connection string, which is why it is trying to connect to a database named after your user ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the database name in your connection string.

The string syntax is as follows:

```
var cn = "postgres://username:password@host:port/database";
```

Alternatively, you can use an object:

```
var cn = {
    host: 'localhost', // server name or IP address;
    port: 5432,
    database: 'my_db_name',
    user: 'user_name',
    password: 'user_password'
};
```

`pg` module can automatically understand which one is being used.

P.S. For a good start with PosgreSQL and Node JS check out [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) ;)